# How can I install Magento themes on localhost?

Tags: magento2

I have downloaded a Magento 2 theme and I want to install that theme to my Magento store. currently I am doing it on my local host.

I am new in Magento and want to install the theme. When I extract the downloaded theme file it gave me 4 directories: app, js, lib, skin and 2 files: .htaccess and robots.txt

Tell me how I can add this theme to my store.

Answer (score 1):

For installing theme on  magento 2 you need to implemeint your theme package to the current magento directory with all the files in designed folder please consider its doc for its file structure first.

Then open cmd using win + R >  type cmd

navigate to your project directory

and run following commands

1- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

2- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

3- `php bin/magentocache:flush`

4- `open admin and select theme from admin>CMS>Theme- Configuration> Your store`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to place the files into your magento root directory. Just be careful so you don't overwrite anything that you shouldn't. After that the theme should be visible into your magento control panel. Go into Stores > Configuration > Design, and change the theme to the one you just uploaded.